# Running javadoc on packages: error - No public or protected classes found to document

Tags: javadoc

I have a such a project, built by MVN:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
  -DartifactId=my-app
```

File Structure

```
--src
  --main
    --java
      --com
        --mycompany
          --app
            --A.java
            --B.java
            --App.java
--pom.xml
--.project
--.classpath
```

For example `A.java` is:

```
package com.mycompany.app;
public class A {
    public void printOut(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I generate the `javadoc` pages using this command successfully:

```
$javadoc -d .\javadoc-gen\ -sourcepath .\src src\main\java\com\mycompany\app\A.java src\main\java\com\mycompany\app\B.java src\main\java\com\mycompany\app\App.java
```

Now I try to address the whole package at once:

```
$javadoc -d .\javadoc-gen\ -sourcepath .\src -subpackages com.mycompany.app
```

I get the following error:

```
Constructing Javadoc information...
javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
1 error
```

I have tested similar variations that I read from tutorials here and there, but Nothing worked. (I know I could generate javadoc via Maven or Eclipse, etc. But this has become a brain-worm.) 
What is wrong with this command?

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me is to leave off the subpackagr specifier:

```
javadoc -d javadoc-gen -sourcepath src/main/java com.mycompany.app
```